# Do I have a Java Virtual Machine on my Windows 7?

Tags: java, jvm

How can I find out if there is Java Virtual Machine installed on my Windows 7?

Comment: Type "java" in your command line (cmd)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open command prompt and type in the following:

```
java -version
```

This should give you the version of the JRE you have installed, something like:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
```

If that fails, you can also check to see if you have any JRE installed. The default location is usually in `${HOME_DIR}\Program Files\Java\`, where `${HOME_DIR}` is usually `C:\`

Comment: The selected answer above is correct but be aware that a response like:
> java version "1.6.0_24" Relates to:
> Java 6 Update 24 This confused me at first. From http://javatester.org/version.html

Answer (score 5):

`Run->cmd` type `java -version`.
If you get complaint for unknown command then Java is not installed.

Comment: What if Java isn't in the path?

Comment: I think the installation always puts the bin directory in the path.I mean I have noticed that I always get `java -version` to respond with the version even if I have not selected java to be in the path during installation

Comment: @Tomas, AFAIK when java is installed a "shortcut/alias" is added in Windows\System32 making it no longer necessary to add java in path

Comment: @Kennet:This is consistent with what I have noticed.I thought it installed bin in the path

Answer (score 2):

@Yahor10 is right. You can first type `java` and then `java -version` in command prompt. If this work you will see that JRE is installed and is in your path.

But if it is not in path you will not know it. So, I prefer to open `regedit` and go to key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft`. If this key does not exist java is not installed. If exists java is typically installed. Previous versions of java created registry entry that showed path where java is installed. I have just checked on my Win7, java1.6-27 and saw that such entry does not exist.

Other way is to got to ControlPanel/Programs and check there.

Answer (score 0):

Either check `java -version` on the command line, look in your installed Software listing (control panel), check whether `Program Files` contains a folder named `Java` or look if there is an environment variable called `JAVA_HOME`.

If neither of those is true, there's a high probability that you don't have a JRE or JDK installed, but that's still not certain. AFAIK Windows 7 doesn't contain a JRE per se, so if you have a clean system you most likely don't have a JRE yet.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to check it online.

http://www.inaplex.com/Products/jvmCheck.aspx 
or

http://javatester.org/version.html

It is working on my system but i am not very sure about its accuracy.

Comment: It will only work if your browser has Java support. It is possible to have a JVM on your system but no Java support in the browser; this answer wouldn't work then.